# Changing the default font on Microsoft Word 2010 has no effect on new pages

Tags: windows-10, fonts, microsoft-word-2010

When I go into the Options/Advanced info on Fonts in Microsoft Word 2010 on Windows 10, I continually change the default font of 11-pt Calibri to 12-pt Times Roman and save it.  However, it never changes when I start a new page.  I have to manually change it all the time.

Comment: "Microsoft 2010" and "Microsoft 10" are not actual products.  What actual product are you talking about?  MS Office 2010?  If so, which program in Office?

Answer (score 3):

Perform the following steps to set the default font for new Microsoft Word 2010 documents.

1. Right click the "Normal" Style on the Home ribbon and click Modify.
2. Change the font to Times New Roman, 12 (or whatever you would prefer).
3. Select the "New documents based on this template" option.
4. Click OK
5. Close and reopen Microsoft Word to confirm.

For Microsoft Excel, perform these steps:

1. Select File menu, Options item.
2. Select the General category.
3. Change "When creating new workbooks, use this font"
4. Click OK to confirm
5. Restart Microsoft Excel as instructed.

Answer (score 3):

*See the below screen shots for steps #2 - #5*

> ### [How to set the default font in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291291)
>
> **How to change the style of the default font in Word 2010**
>
> To change the style of the default font in Word 2010, follow these
>   steps:
>
> 1. If you do not have a document open, create a new document that is
>      based on the Normal template. To do this, click **File,** click **New,**
>      click **Blank Document**, and then click **Create**.
> 2. In the **Font** group, click the **Font** flyout.
> 3. Select the options that you want to apply to the default font, such
>      as font style and font size. If you selected specific text, the
>      properties of the selected text are set in the dialog box.
> 4. Click **Set As Default**.
> 5. Select the **All documents based on the Normal.dotm template?** option,
>      and then click OK.
>
> <sub>[source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291291)</sub>

### Screen Shots

[image]
[image]